# Creating an S3 bucket and adding a file using the Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Is it possible to specify a static file to upload to an S3 bucket resource in my serverless.yaml file?

i.e.

```
resources:
  Resources:
   PropertiesBucket:
     Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
     Properties:
       BucketName: ${self:provider.stage}-MyBucket
     File:
        ./myfile.json
        ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a static file to an S3 bucket is not supported by any official AWS CloudFormation resources, but [gilt/cloudformation-helpers](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers) has a custom resource, [Put S3 Objects](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers#put-s3-objects), that can do this. See [Usage](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers#usage) for instructions on installation and usage.

Comment: Thanks @wjordan. Seeing as I want to stick to the serverless framework for now I will just hold off until CloudFormation adds this feature. Can look to integrate serverless with it then. Many thanks.